# ISO C++ forbids declaration of .. with no type with --std=c++0x set

Tags: c++, c++11

In my c++ code I'm using the `auto` type, to enable c++11, I add the flag `--std=c++0x` to my makefile, but I still get error of `ISO C++ forbids declaration of .. with no type`, if I enable c++11 with `-std=gnu++11` or `-std=c++11`, I got `cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "..."`, my gcc version is `4.3.4`, how should I solve this? Thank you.

Without enabling c++11, I got error of `ISO C++ forbids declaration of wallclock with no type` the following line:

```
auto wallclock  = time(nullptr);
```

Comment: Would be **really** helpful if you posted runnable code for us to reproduce your error

Comment: Makefile is good, but to understand what the error is, we'd need to see your SOURCE!

Comment: @EdChum I added my makefile, and there's nothing special in my code but just an `auto` type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support for `auto`-typed variables was not implemented in GCC before version 4.4. The version you are using is too old.

See support matrix: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Comment: You should link to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/cxx0x_status.html) instead.